# footer is refusing to stick to bottom

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, footer

Learning HTML and CSS and have come up with something I just don’t comprehend.

Does anyone know why exactly my footer is showing up nearly the top of the page.

Heres what I thought I am doing right,

1)  Place the correct footer HTML at the bottom of the page

2)  Add my core footer CSS so it always stays at the bottom and is responsive

Codepen - https://codepen.io/nightcoder21/pen/BxwVdJ

my html

```
  <footer>
    <div id="icons">
      <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>

    </div>
    <p class="text-center">yadayada</p>
  </footer>
```

Apart from getting a solution from someone more experience I would appreciate if someone can tell me exactly where I have gone wrong so I can learn.

Thank you for reading

Cheers

Comment: Swap absolute for footer to fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to your `body` tag.

Updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/deJwrw

Comment: do you know why the FB social icon is not lining up with the rest of the icons?..thanks

Comment: @Ravi21 you have `padding-bottom: 2.3rem;` on the `.fab` class (twice) in your css. see this updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRZYrg)